# Iterate fields of model according to a pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model which has following fields: x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ..., xn, yn, zn

I want to iterate the fields so that in each iteration, I want to get these: xN, yN, zN. Is there any way to do this? The purpose is that I do not want to manually write forms for these many fields.

Answer (score 0):

> Hurrah for laziness!

```
Model.find(1) = @model

form_for @model do |f|
@attributes = @model.attributes.except("x1", "y1", "z1") *and so on.*
```

*The above returns a hash, which you can then do the following within the form.*

```
@attributes.each_key do |key|
f.text_field key.to_sym
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple iteration in `ruby` to demonstrate one simple way to do this:

```
chars    = ['x', 'y', 'z']
numbers  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

chars.each do |char|
  numbers.each do |number|
    puts "#{char}#{number}"
  end
end
```

this logs:

> x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 .....

which gives you access to the fields.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have x1,y1,z1..x10,y10,z10 and if you need text boxes for all your fields, you can write your form like this

```
<%(1..10).each do |n|%>
 <%=f.text_field "x#{n}".to_sym %>
 <%=f.text_field "y#{n}".to_sym %>
 <%=f.text_field "z#{n}".to_sym %>
<%end%>
```

If you don't care about the order of the attributes, then

```
   <% @object.attributes.keys.each do |attribute| %>
      <%=f.text_field attribute.to_sym %>
   <% end %
```

In the above case, all you fields will be listed in the form in no particular order.